# Calling a Function from Within a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

If I have a case where I have a simple logging function in my main file:

```
def log_events(data_to_log):
    log_this = '%s - %s' % (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), data_to_log)
    print ('%s\r' % log_this[0:140])
    hlog_file = open('%s' % LOG_FILE_NAME, 'a')
    print ( log_this, file=hlog_file)
    hlog_file.close()
```

I have different classes for different tasks. I want to reuse the same log function in every class i make. This is in a file called. doit.py

```
class DoStuff:

    def __init__ (self, extra_stuff_):
        self.some_extra_stuff = extra_stuff

    def do_the_thing(self):
        x = 1
        log_events( ' x is currently %s' % x )
        x = 2
        log_events( ' x is currently %s' % x )
        log_events( ' extra stuff is %s' % self.some_extra_stuff )
```

Now the final code:

```
import doit

def log_events(data_to_log):
    log_this = '%s - %s' % (strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), data_to_log)
    print ('%s\r' % log_this[0:140])
    hlog_file = open('%s' % LOG_FILE_NAME, 'a')
    print ( log_this, file=hlog_file)
    hlog_file.close()

things_i_want_to_do = doit.DoStuff('this is the stuff')
things_i_want_to_do.do_the_thing()
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'log_events' is not defined
```

Is there a better way of sharing that log_events function with all the imported classes?

Comment: Any file that you want to be able to use your logger should import your logger

Comment: Its not a its own class it is part of the main file.

Comment: "Is there a better way of sharing that log_events function" You haven't shared it at all. Do so.

Comment: The logger should be moved into it's own file if you need to share it with many other files. You'll have to import this logger in every python file that you want to be able to access the logger.

Comment: Got it. I figured since it was part of the main script I would not have to seperate it into a file and import it each time.